# Como cambiarle el background a un nz-drawer usando angular?

Tags: css, angular, ant-design

tenia este inconveniente al aplicar un estilo css usando ng-zorro para angular, estuve buscando y muchos dicen que es

```
<nz-drawer class="menu-background">
...
</nz-drawer>
```

y poniendo en mi clase de css

```
.menu-background{
    background-color: rgba($color: #212121, $alpha: .5);
}
```

mas sin embargo cambio no se aplica, entonces nos se si hay una solucion concreta ya que por lo que eh visto en la pagina no eh encontrado algo para cambiarle el color o hacerlo transparente, tengo que aclarar que estoy usando angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por la estructura que tiene el componente puedes hacer esto:

```
 ::ng-deep .ant-drawer-content{
     background-color: transparent;
  }
 ::ng-deep .ant-drawer-header{
     background-color: transparent;
 }
 ::ng-deep .ant-drawer-body{
     background-color: transparent;
 }
```

`::ng-deep` permite romper la encapsulación de estilos para que puedas modificar los estilos internos del `drawer`.

`.ant-drawer-content` `.ant-drawer-header` `.ant-drawer-body` son clases estructurales a las que se les aplica el fondo transparente.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-khorana-bkj1o?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)